# issues on download Apache Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat

I am trying to install Apache Tomcat, but I find to different files:

one is CORE while another is Deployer

which one should I choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download CORE. From the documentation:

> the Client Deployer, which is a command shell based script that interacts with the Tomcat Manager but provides additional functionality such as compiling and validating web applications as well as packaging web application into web application resource (WAR) files

The deployer is just a tool. It does not include the Tomcat server.